# Assigning Domain URL to my Virtual Host

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost

I setup my own static website using CentOS 7 on a virtual machine with a bridged network. The static site has a self-signed certificate and can be already accessed on the same network. How do I assign it with a domain name? I've already configured the Virtual Host File and I can't access it.

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/example.com/requests.log combined
```

Is it possible even I don't buy a domain name?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Are you trying to publish this site to a large audience, or just a few servers ?  Also is it accessible by IP address, for example http://10.0.0.1/public_html ?  If not, then name resolution isn't the only issue.

Comment: @PatrickTaylor i'm just trying to for local access, yes it is accessible through IP address